# Quartz-scheduler scheduling job every 2 weeks ignoring previous misfires

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm trying to schedule a job on a given day (user defined) on an interval of every 2 weeks and ignoring and previous misfires using Quartz-Scheduler.

For example:
If I set the start date to 7th Oct(Sunday) and today's date is 26th Oct, it should trigger on 4th Nov(Sunday), 18th Nov(Sunday)...

The only way I found to do this is using the `WithCalendarIntervalSchedule` extension with `StartAt`. The issue with this approach is that, if the start date is before today then all the misfires will be triggered when the trigger is being scheduled.

Cron expression and CronScheduleBuilder does not seem to allow this.

I cannot ignore misfires as i do not want triggers that failed to start on time for whatever reason to be ignored.
And i cannot force the start date to be after today.

Let me know if I'm missing anything, I've been looking for a solution to this for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Quartz scheduler does not support schedule for every 2 weeks very well.

The trick to make it work is to set the start date to be the next DateTime that it should be triggered using the StartAt extension then use WithCalendarIntervalSchedule with WithIntervalInWeeks.